# Calculate $4||x+y||2+||x−y||2 $

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

Let's take $x, y \in X$ where $X$ is vector space with norm inducted by inner product.

Additionally $||3x+y||= 2$, $||x+3y|| = 2$.

I want to calculate $4||x+y||^2+||x-y||^2$ $\\$

**My work so far**

Because $X$ has a norm inducted by inner product then for $x,y \in X$ we have $$||x+y||^2 + ||x-y||^2 = 2(||x||^2+||y||^2)$$

So:

$4||x+y||^2 + ||x-y||^2 = 3||x+y||^2 + (||x+y||^2 + ||x-y||^2)  = 3||x+y||^2 + 2(||x||^2 + ||y||^2)$

And I'm not sure why to do next... I'm not sure how can I was trying to rewrite this expression to somehow include information that $||3x+y|| = ||x+3y|| = 2$ but I wasn't able to. Could you please give me a hint how it can be calculated ?

Comment: Side note: `\Vert x \Vert` renders as $\Vert x \Vert $, which looks a bit nicer for the norm.

Comment: The title has $\|4x+y\|$ as the first term of the expression, but in the question body it's $4\|x+y\|$ instead. Which one do you mean? I'd wager it's the latter, since it seems more tractable. And if that's the case, would you mind editing the title to reflect that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with the parallelogram law. Apply it to $u=3x+y$ and $v=x+3y$:
$$
 16 = 2 (\Vert 3x+y\Vert^2 + \Vert x+3y\Vert^2 ) = \Vert 4x+ 4y \Vert^2 + \Vert 2x - 2y \Vert^2 \\
= 16 \Vert x+y \Vert^2 + 4 \Vert x-y \Vert^2 = 4 (4\Vert x+y \Vert^2 +  \Vert x-y \Vert^2)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that
$$\|x \pm y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2 \pm 2\Re\langle x, y \rangle.$$